# Cannot see maven dependencies in a uml class diagram in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm tryin to see my maven dependencies in IntelliJ following the instructions found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-maven-dependencies.html#1). I can open the maven project tool window, but I can't see any option to show the class diagram. I have the free version 14.1.4

Comment: Do you see the terminal at the bottom of Intellij-Idea, click that and give ' mvn dependency:tree'  and you will see it in console. If you don't see the terminal option, on left-side bottom, there would be one single icon, click it and you will get a bottom menu which has terminal.

Comment: This is not quite as user friendly as using the Class Diagram...

Comment: Well, atleast you have it. If someone knows how to get it, they can help you. For now this is, secondly, it's not that bad!!!#

Comment: Yeah, in my case, I am giving IntelliJ a try to see if it's worth ditching my good ol' Eclipse. So user friendliness is a big deal ;)

Comment: Well, I use Intellij, code-completion, indexing capabilities of Intellij are far superior as compared to Eclipse, especially when they started making it as a Platform, it kept going worst. Also, no refresh and all that BS. But it's paid. So, decide carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with Community Edition.

The "Show Dependencies" action depend on IDEA's UML plugin, which is included in Ultimate Edition only.